# How call function using variable in js?

Tags: javascript

for example, I have code like this:

```
var test = function() {
   return Math.random();
}

var randomNumber = test();


// I want to call test() via the randomNumber variable, 
// use this variable on another function or etc...
// for example here
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log(randomNumber); // and it should be show 4 random numbers
}
```

Is this possible? 
Thanks to advance.

Comment: do you mean to use a variable when calling a function? like `randomNumber = test(); console.log(randomNumber);` ?

Comment: I guess you might want to create a so-called "getter". To do so, have a look at `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: I have updated question.

Comment: Now I have just 1 number, which was generated when I create a randomNumber variable.

Comment: If you want a new random number in each iteration just call the function - ... console.log(test());

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to assign the function reference to `randomNumber` instead of calling the function and assigning its return value.

```js
var test = function() {
   return Math.random();
}

// Assign test to randomNumber, but don't call it here
var randomNumber = test;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log(randomNumber()); // call it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the value returned by the function to the variable inside the loop and then display it.

Kinda like the code below

```js
// define function
var test = function() {
  return Math.random();
}

// define variable
var randomNumber;

// loop
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // invoke function, assign value to variable
  randomNumber = test();

  // output it to console.
  console.log(randomNumber);
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you do not want to write code to 'loop' thru your array, you can use a fake array and map the same function to it.

You are not looping thru it yourself but looping thru the array is being performed nonetheless.

```js
// array of fake values
var iterations = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

// returns an array of random numbers
console.log(iterations.map(function(elem) {
  return Math.random();
}));
```

Comment: yes this way works already, but I wanna find a way without simple loop (if it possible of course)

Comment: @ArikDonowan I am not sure I understand what you mean by *without simple loop* - can you explain?

Comment: Perhaps better questions for you are: what are you trying to achieve? and why are you trying to avoid a loop?